# android teamviewer intent with parameters

Tags: android, remote-control

Is there a way to start in android the "teamviewer" app (or another similar app which let you remote control the phone) specifing which "user id" and password are required to control the device?

for example:

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.teamviewer");
i.putExtra("id_key", "123456789");
i.putExtra("password", "1234");
startActivity(i);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent i = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile");
      i.putExtra("id_key", "123456789");
      i.putExtra("password", "1234");
      startActivity(i);
```

Comment: how about for com.teamviewer.host.market? I tried `id_key` and `password` but to no avail.